# Getting (changing) embedded Excel range displayed in a Word document using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, ole

In my Word document there are many embedded Excel spreadsheets. Usually these Excel embeddings are bigger than the small portion shown in Word. I don't want to mess with the whole sheet when I enter the embedded file, I need to edit only this small area which is seen in Word. I know that it is only a picture, but when you `ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).OLEFormat.Edit`, exactly the same small area opens in edit mode. I need to get the range of this area in order to be able to work only with this portion of the worksheet.
I currently use these variables:

```
    Dim wrdActDoc As Document
        Set wrdActDoc = ActiveDocument
    Dim oOleFormat As OLEFormat
    Dim oWS As Excel.Worksheet
        Set oOleFormat = wrdActDoc.InlineShapes(1).OLEFormat
        Set oWS = oOleFormat.Object.ActiveSheet
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in Excel's `ActiveWindow.VisibleRange`, you can probably fetch that from your `oOleFormat.Object`.